# Can't run app in Samsung TV emulator

Tags: emulation, samsung-smart-tv

I have created an project from Eclipse provided by Samsung smartTVSDK, but when I run this project in the emulator, the emulator always show "connecting", and the console report an error like this

```
    [JS ERROR]:
File:           file://d/Program%20Files/Samsung/Samsung%20TV%20SDK(3.5.2)/Emulator/Emulator2012_v3.5/commonlib/ch_nonsec/SmartHome/SmartHomeMain.js.smk
Line No:        3933
Error Detail:   TypeError: 'null' is not an object (evaluating 'userCPInfo[widgetCPName]')
```

Comment: You must give more informations, code snippets and more background about the application.

Answer (score 0):

Try to Reset the Virtual Box from the menu and refresh the app.